# Disable wadl Web Service Definition In CXF

Tags: cxf, cxfrs

I am using CXF webservice and everything is working perfectly. But as I am going to expose our webservice to public the wadl url is working from public. Anyone can see the wadl definition of our webservice.

How can we disable this definition.

e.g. the url for wadl is - http://localhost:8080/webservice/rest?_wadl

Comment: Were you able to disable it? Let me know if you still having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to `jaxrs:server`, this will hide the endpoint exposed by the `jaxrs:server` address

```
<jaxrs:properties>
   <entry key="org.apache.cxf.endpoint.private" value="true"/>
 </jaxrs:properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

wadl is generated thanks to the following dependency.

cxf-rt-rs-service-description

if you remove that jar from the application/dependency management no wadl will be generated.

Additional information:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-WADLAutoGenerationatRuntime

Comment: I am using single jar :( cxf-2.7.10.jar. How to remove in this case?

Comment: @Neeraj Sorry, I use 3.0.3. But if you only want to expose some services you can deactivate it with [cxf doc](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-HidinglinkstoJAXRSendpointsfromtheservicespage)